# No time for an emperor

Tags: riddle

> I'm one word, made from two parts.   
> Before this clause, some people I asked.
> One thought it was time to take chances! 
> Another left to go where the dance is. 
> Because they were lateral and did not combine   
> In truth, of battle I am a sign.

Hint:

> In a very broad sense, the second word can be used to mean "applicator". <s>This is the logic behind lines 2 and 5.</s>

Hint 2:

> Thus, lines 3 and 4 describe the first word.

Hint 3 + requirement specification:

> The title could be as much useful as the entire riddle, and its explanation is needed for the answer.

Hint 4:

> The calamity woman loves hers.

Hint 5:

> Spreads, amount depends on type.

Hint 6:

> Very dangerous up-close

Comment: The pending edit from cwallenpoole will do the trick. In future put two spaces after each line before going on to the next line. Then you won't need the extra in-between lines.

Comment: @George Any hint?

Comment: Its been a while now, can we get any more hints?

Comment: I have a possible answer which seems to match a lot of the details, although I'm still sketchy on the title and hints 5/6. Can I check before I go further down this route - is the answer related to rot13(pbzchgre tnzrf, fcrpvsvpnyyl sbe zbovyr)? Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv sorry, no. But...I fear it may be a bad(dly defined) riddle in the end. It should have been found. I think it would help the community and me if you posted one try.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Ah, okay. Well I think I have word#1 - if I can come up with a good companion for it I'll post an attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but I'll take a shot at the answer:

> **Shotgun**

Line 1:

> **shot** + **gun**

Title + Hint 3:

> With no '**t**' - the symbol of time - in the answer, we get **shogun**: Shoguns were military dictators appointed by the emperor in Japan, but became *de facto* rulers over time.

Hint 1:

> A "gun" such as a soldering gun is an applicator of sorts.

Hint 2 + Lines 3 and 4:

> Line 3: Taking a shot means taking a chance. 
>  Line 4: Related to a shot of liquor, perhaps?

Hint 4:

> <s>There's a film titled "Loves Her Gun" (hadn't heard of it before)</s> 
>  EDIT (with the help of OP and Wikipedia): [Calamity Jane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calamity_Jane) was a gunslinger, and also appears in [Lucky Luke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Luke)

Hint 5:

> Shotgun fire spreads out (by different amounts depending on the type of shotgun)

Hint 6:

> Evidently more dangerous at closer range before the shot spreads

Line 6:

> Guns are a sign of battle

Comment: Correct! Lines 2 and 5 are very unfortunate...I removed them from the hint. Hint 4, though, has to do with Lucky Luke. Any ideas?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis : Updated.  BTW, one of my earlier guesses for Line 6 was rot13(pebffjbeqf) => rot13(pebff fjbeqf) -- maybe an idea for another puzzle...